# Swagger UI using C# webApi is changing my header parameter to query parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, swagger

So I decided to use this method since it's the simplest to add custom headers for my api calls, example:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("something")]
public async Task<somethingObject> DoSomething([Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromHeader(Name = "deviceGuid")] string deviceGuid)
{
    var somethingObject= await doSomethingWithDevice(deviceGuid)
    return somethingObject;
}
```

The expected outcome from this is a field in Swagger where I can input the deviceGuid and Swagger should consider it as a header.

Issue at hand is that Swagger is considering it a query and not a header:

[image]

Any clue how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think SwashBuckle (im guessing this is the swagger implementation you're using), knows about FromHeader.
What you could do, is this;
Make an OperationFilter that changes the ParameterType to Header - something like the following; - note I found this in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/0xced/d679d43bb7dd8a9ab805db43e561e48d).

```
public class FromHeaderAttributeOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        foreach (var httpParameterDescriptor in apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters().Where(e => e.GetCustomAttributes<FromHeaderAttribute>().Any()))
        {
            var parameter = operation.parameters.Single(p => p.name == httpParameterDescriptor.ParameterName);
            parameter.name = httpParameterDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<FromHeaderAttribute>().Single().HeaderName;
            parameter.@in = "header";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using            

    if (apiDescription.RelativePath.Contains("/registration"))
            { add custom headers }

Comment: You can do that aswell - works perfect when you only got the one route to fix :)

Comment: Yeah I had 2-3 routes so I ended up using 3 ifs to check the routes, more of a quick nice fix than a permanent one though!